# If ∇f(x,y,z,w) = <0,0,0,0>, then which is true?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

a) f is a scalar
b) f is a vector

Although this may seem like an easy answer, I'm not sure if...

f is a scalar because to get the components inside the vector you need to take the derivative, which would result in 0's if it were a scalar.

OR

f is a vector because... it's in vector form. I don't think this is the case as the gradient ∇ is the vector.

Am i right/wrong?

Comment: It *really* looks as if $f$ is a function.

Comment: The four options were a) vector b) scalar c) ∇f(x,y,z,w)=w^2 or
d) f(x,y,z,w)=(w^2)(sin(x))

Comment: These are the four optioanl *answers*, but what is the *question*?

Comment: As stated in the question, if ∇f(x,y,z,w) = <0, 0, 0, 0> then it is possible that f is.... a), b), c), or d)

Comment: It's a silly question (not your fault, of course). None of the options is correct. The closest one is a), because $f$ is a scalar *function*. But it is not correct to state that $f$ is a scalar.

Comment: May I ask why it's incorrect to say that $f$ is a scalar? The set of bijective functions is indeed a field, isn't it?